# Path of file for Catalog, Manage Products, Add Product - In that Save button

Tags: magento-1.7, product, admin, adminhtml, controllers

I am new to Magento. Please can anyone tell me the path of file in Magento's admin panel - Catalog, Manage Products, Add Product - In that Save button.

**Where the code is written for saving products in admin panel?**

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you look into `app/code/core/Mage` to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the code that saves the products under `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php` in the `saveAction()` method

Comment: @jassi feel free to mark your question as answered so it'll benefit for others

Comment: You can tell me how you found the path?

Comment: @jassi I knew it ^^ but basically in Magento the URL http://your.store.com/route/controllername/action will match `app/code/core/Mage/Modulewiththatroute/controllers/ControllernameController.php` with `actionAction()` method

Comment: you are so fast :)

Comment: I have print the value for Product in both frontend and admin but value for store_id differs. In frontend it gives 1 and at backend it gives 0. Any specific reason why?

Comment: @jassi not sure, please open a new question for that